# WPF application closes when writing to a text file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a desktop application in WPF `.NET Framework` and whenever I try to create several text files on load and then write to them, via `File.WriteAllLines` - the program lags and then the window closes. It is not showing any exceptions or problems in the output window. Here is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string FolderPath = @"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA";
    public string Person1Path = @"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\Person1.txt";
    public string Person2Path = @"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\Person2.txt";
    public string Person3Path = @"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\Person3.txt";
    public string Person4Path = @"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\Person4.txt";
    public string Person5Path = @"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\Person5.txt";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create Folder
        if(!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        //Create File 1
        if (!File.Exists(Person1Path))
        {
            File.Create(Person1Path);
            string[] DefaultData1 = {"Person 1", "0"};
            File.WriteAllLines(Person1Path, DefaultData1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        //Create File 2
        if (!File.Exists(Person2Path))
        {
            File.Create(Person2Path);
            string[] DefaultData2 = { "Person 2", "0" };
            File.WriteAllLines(Person2Path, DefaultData2);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        //Create File 3
        if (!File.Exists(Person3Path))
        {
            File.Create(Person3Path);
            string[] DefaultData3 = { "Person 3", "0" };
            File.WriteAllLines(Person3Path, DefaultData3);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        //Create File 4
        if (!File.Exists(Person4Path))
        {
            File.Create(Person4Path);
            string[] DefaultData4 = { "Person 4", "0" };
            File.WriteAllLines(Person4Path, DefaultData4);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        //Create File 5
        if (!File.Exists(Person5Path))
        {
            File.Create(Person5Path);
            string[] DefaultData5 = { "Person 5", "0" };
            File.WriteAllLines(Person5Path, DefaultData5);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: add `try {} catch(Exception ex) {}` block around file operation and you will likely intercept the exception

Comment: Next step would be to create files in a loop, instead of duplicating code five times.

Comment: Next step is to refactor your code to create dictionary and file

Comment: It's also not necessary to call `File.Create` when you call `File.WriteAllLines`. The latter will implicitly create a file. Remove all the `File.Create` calls.

Comment: The exception is displayed as "The process cannot access the file 'C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\Person1.txt' because it is being used by another process". Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: put your code in a using statement it should dispose the object and close the connection

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum Not at all. Just don't call File.Create and hence don't get a FileStream to dispose.

Comment: @Clemens You were right, that fixed the problem - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually quite simple.

When you use the `File.Create` the file is indeed created, but the lock that is placed on it by `File.Create` does not release automatically. This means that when you try to write in the file using `File.WriteAllLines` the File is inaccessible, since it's used by another process.

In your case the fix is actually quite simple, you can simply get rid of the `File.Create` calls since `File.WriteAllLines` will create the file if the file does not exists.

So your code should look like this :

```
if (!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            //Create File 1
            if (!File.Exists(Person1Path))
            {
                string[] DefaultData1 = { "Person 1", "0" };
                File.WriteAllLines(Person1Path, DefaultData1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            //Create File 2
            if (!File.Exists(Person2Path))
            {
                string[] DefaultData2 = { "Person 2", "0" };
                File.WriteAllLines(Person2Path, DefaultData2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            //Create File 3
            if (!File.Exists(Person3Path))
            {
                string[] DefaultData3 = { "Person 3", "0" };
                File.WriteAllLines(Person3Path, DefaultData3);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            //Create File 4
            if (!File.Exists(Person4Path))
            {
                string[] DefaultData4 = { "Person 4", "0" };
                File.WriteAllLines(Person4Path, DefaultData4);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            //Create File 5
            if (!File.Exists(Person5Path))
            {
                string[] DefaultData5 = { "Person 5", "0" };
                File.WriteAllLines(Person5Path, DefaultData5);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
```

Also as many of the comments points out, there is plenty of way to refactor your code to make it more readable, and less error prone.